# Powershell file property listing

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, file, properties

I'm trying to collect some file properties using PowerShell within Win 2008. To do so, I've created the following script.

```pwsh
# BASIC PARAMETER IF NOT SET
param(
    $REGEX='.*'
    )

# CURRENT DATE FROM 00H
$DATAATUAL = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Day 1 # DAY 1 FOR TESTING ONLY

# APPLICATION'S FILE PATH
$PATH = "C:\FTP\import\"

# FILE LIST WITH SELECTED FILES FROM REGULAR EXPRESSION
$FILELIST = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATH | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -ge $DATAATUAL) -and ($_.Name -cmatch "$REGEX") } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# OUTPUT IN A SORT OF CSV FORMAT
if ($FILELIST -ne $null) {

    Write-Host "name;suffix;fileprocstart;filesize;filewrite"

    ForEach ($FILE in $FILELIST) {
        
        # FILE NAME PREFIX AND SUFFIX
        $FILENAME = Select-String -InputObject $FILE -CaseSensitive -Pattern "(^\d+)_($REGEX)"
        
        # FILE TIMESTAMP CONVERSION TO EPOCH UTC-0
        $FILEPROCSTART = $FILENAME.Matches.Groups[1].value
            $FILEPROCSTART = [datetime]::ParseExact($FILEPROCSTART,"yyyyMMddHHmmss",$null) | Get-Date -UFormat "%s"
            $FILEPROCSTART = $($FILEPROCSTART -as [long]) + 10800  # TIMEZONE CORRECTION - ADDED 3H TO BECOME UTC-0
                        
        $FILESUFFIX = $FILENAME.Matches.Groups[2].value
        
        # FILE SIZE AND WRITE TIME
        $FILESIZE = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATH -Filter $FILE | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length
        $FILEWRITE = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATH -Filter $FILE | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime | Get-Date -UFormat "%s"
        
        # OUTPUT
        Write-Host "$FILENAME;$FILESUFFIX;$FILEPROCSTART;$FILESIZE;$FILEWRITE"
    }
}

# NO FILES FOUND
Else {
    Write-Host "Empty"
}
```

I can start it like so:

`script.ps1 -REGEX 'pattern'`

It results in a list like this:

```
name;suffix;fileprocstart;filesize;filewrite
20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt;cacs1_v83.txt;1657361472;5;1657397022,47321
20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt.log;cacs1_v83.txt.log;1657361472;5;1657397041,83271
20220709101112_cacs2_v83.txt;cacs2_v83.txt;1657361472;5;1657397039,70775
20220709101112_cacs3_v83.txt.log;cacs3_v83.txt.log;1657361472;5;1657397038,03647
20220709101112_cakauto4.txt;cakauto4.txt;1657361472;5;1657397037,48906
20220709111112_coord_multicanal.txt.log;coord_multicanal.txt.log;1657365072;5;1657398468,95865
```

All files are generated on a daily basis and have a format similar to this:

```
20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt
20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt.log
20220709101112_cacs2_v83.txt
20220709101112_cacs3_v83.txt.log
20220709101112_cakauto4.txt
20220709101112_coord_multicanal.txt.log
```

Basically, the script outputs the file name, file suffix (no timestamp), file timestamp (unix format), file size and Last Write time (unix format), all in a sort of CSV format. It is meant to be started by another system to collect those properties.

It kind of works, but I can't help thinking there must be a better way to do that.

Any considerations on how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) great tips, I've rewritten the script this way.

```pwsh
param($REGEX='.*')
$DATAATUAL = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Day 1 # DAY 1 FOR TESTING ONLY
$PATH = "C:\FTP\import"
$TZ = [TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time")

$FILELIST = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATH |
    Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -ge $DATAATUAL) -and ($_.Name -cmatch "$REGEX") } |
        Select-Object -Property Name,Length,
            @{Name = 'Suffix'; Expression = { ($_.Name -split '_',2)[1] } },
            @{Name = 'ProcStart'; Expression = {
                $PROCSTART = ($_.Name -split '_')[0]; 
                $PROCSTART = [datetime]::ParseExact($PROCSTART,"yyyyMMddHHmmss",$null);
                [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeToUtc($PROCSTART, $TZ) | Get-Date -UFormat "%s";
                } },
            @{Name = 'FileWrite' ; Expression = {
                $WRITETIME = $_.LastWriteTime;
                [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeToUtc($WRITETIME) | Get-Date -UFormat "%s";
                } }


if ($FILELIST -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "name;suffix;procstart;filesize;filewrite"
    # $FILELIST | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation

    ForEach ($FILE in $FILELIST) {
        $FILENAME = $FILE.Name
        $FILESUFFIX = $FILE.Suffix
        $FILESIZE = $FILE.Length
        $FILEPROCSTART = $FILE.ProcStart
        $FILEWRITE = $FILE.FileWrite
        
        Write-Host "$FILENAME;$FILESUFFIX;$FILESIZE;$FILEPROCSTART;$FILEWRITE"
    }
} 
Else {
    Write-Host "Empty"
}
```

As said, the output is in a CSV format.

```
name;suffix;procstart;filesize;filewrite
20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt;cacs1_v83.txt;5;1657361472;1657397022,47321
20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt.log;cacs1_v83.txt.log;5;1657361472;1657397041,83271
```

If I use `ConvertTo-Csv` (much simpler) instead of `ForEach`, the output would also be a CSV.
However, it places quotation marks that mess up other conversions to JSON elsewhere (maybe I can improve that later).

```
# $FILELIST | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
"Name";"Length";"Suffix";"ProcStart";"FileWrite"
"20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt";"5";"cacs1_v83.txt";"1657361472";"1657397022,47321"
"20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt.log";"5";"cacs1_v83.txt.log";"1657361472";"1657397041,83271"
```

The other system convert it to this (I can't use ConvertTo-Json in Win2008 :-/):

```
{
  "\"Name\"": "\"20220709101112_cacs1_v83.txt\"",
  "\"Length\"": "\"5\"",
  "\"Suffix\"": "\"cacs1_v83.txt\"",
  "\"ProcStart\"": "\"1657361472\"",
  "\"FileWrite\"": "\"1657397022,47321\""
}
```

Therefore, I find that writing the values with `ForEach` gives me a cleaner output.

Also, for fun, measuring with Measure-Command, I found that the new script is a bit faster.
The previous script takes about 24 milliseconds to complete while using a small dataset.
Now, the new one takes about 13 milliseconds with the same dataset.

All in all, a small, but good improvement, I guess.

Cheers to [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) for pointing to a better script and for his patience. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it right but if I understand this right:

> Basically, the script outputs the file name, file suffix, file name timestamp, file size and Last Write time, all in a sort of CSV format. It is meant to be started by another system to collect those properties.

This should be all you need to start with:

```
$ComputerName = 'RemoteW2K8Computer'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\FTP\import' |
        Select-Object -Property BaseName,Extension,Length,LastWriteTime,
            @{Name = 'FileNameTimeStamp'; Expression = {($_.BaseName -split '_')[0]}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.
I'm not sure that would account for the daily and regular expression filters.
Also, I'm extracting the timestamp from the file name, the LastWriteTime and transforming to Epoch time.
I guess I was not clear about that in my question. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Of course you can add any calculated property you need. I just wanted to show that you don't need to use the same `Get-ChildItem` several times.

Comment: I guess that's what I aim for. But how so?

Comment: I added an example to show how it's done.

Comment: I've managed to do it like this:
```$FILELIST = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATH |
 Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -ge $DATAATUAL) -and ($_.Name -cmatch "$REGEX") } |
  Select-Object -Property BaseName,Length,
   @{Name = 'FileSuffix'; Expression = { ($_.BaseName -split '_',2)[1] } },
   @{Name = 'FileTimeStamp'; Expression = { [datetime]::ParseExact(($_.BaseName -split '_')[0],"yyyyMMddHHmmss",$null) | Get-Date -UFormat "%s" } },
   @{Name = 'WriteTime' ; Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime | Get-Date -UFormat "%s" } }```
But how to display it in a CSV format?

Comment: If you want to display it in the console you can use `Format-Table`. To have it in an actual CSV file you use `Export-Csv`

Comment: I need the output as a CSV. Pretty much like shown above.
`Format-Table` displays data in a pretty way, but not useful for the other system.
Since the script will be trigged almost every minute from the other system, I don't think writing a CSV is necessary.

I found `ConvertTo-Csv` useful and it was almost perfect in this scenario. Unfortunately, it adds a bunch of literal quotation marks.
The other system can't read the data correctly that way.

Comment: I'd recommend to read the help for `ConvertTo-Csv` completely including the examples to learn how to use it. ;-)  ... especially about the parameter `-NoTypeInformation`

Comment: `-NoTypeInformation` did remove the initial comment, but did not remove the quotation marks.

Comment: The quotes around the cell content in CSV is part of the standard and every standard compliant tool shouldn't have a problem with it.   ;-)